# Get alert boc using clientscript.registerstarupscript()

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, alert

I am facing an issue in `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` in an asp.net 2.0 application. I am not getting alert message when I used the above specified instead of `Response.Write()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script block added by the RegisterStartupScript method executes when the page finishes loading but before the page's OnLoad event is raised

**Reference URL:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx